# How to access stage in global scope outside of handler function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to be able to access the name of API GW stage that was invoked in global scope (i.e. outside of the handler function).

In my Lambda, I want to create my DB connection pool in global scope so that it has the potential to be reused by subsequent Lambda invocations (thereby potentially improving the performance of such subsequent invocations).  The connection pool is obviously configuration driven - and I will need to be able to have different configuration values used for each stage (and I would access the appropriate values based upon that stage name).

The trouble is that I cannot seem to find any way of determining the stage name until I am within the actual handler invocation (provided within the event object hierarchy).

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
const stageName = <????how to get this???>;
const config = require(`./${stageName}/config`);
const pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : config.dbconnectionLimit,
    host            : config.dbhost,
    port            : config.dbport,
    user            : config.dbuser,
    password        : config.dbpassword,
});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 let response = {};

 // NOTE: I can easily access the stageName here as event.context.stage
 // as well as any stageVariables under event['stage-variable'].<stageVariableName>
 // However, this is too late to realize the potential performance benefit across
 // subsequent lambda invocations by creating the DB pool in global scope 
 // as opposed to locally within the handler itself

 // ... lambda implementation here (omitted for brevity)  

 return response;
};
```

Comment: Do you use `serverless`?

Comment: yes, am using both a serverless SAM deployment as well as a serverless RDS instance in this case

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about `serverless-framework`.

Comment: Is this `stageName` something you hard code manually or a dynamic value?

Comment: the stageName is determined/specified by the API Gateway.  So it is dynamic and out of control from the perspective of the Lambda itself.